# SQL Command c# not getting the right results

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm running the following query

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE identifier NOT IN(@notIn)", _connector.getMsConnection());
```

When I view the value notIn and copy this query I get an empty result on my database (which I'm expecting). However when I'm running this code I get 6 results. The content of **string** notIN is for example

```
string notIn = "'201619011124027899693E8M2S3WOCKT9G6KHE11' ,'201619011124027899693E8M2S3WOCKT9G6KHE12'"
```

which combined with

```
SELECT * 
FROM addresses 
WHERE identifier NOT IN(@notIn)
```

Should create

```
SELECT * 
FROM addresses 
WHERE identifier NOT IN ('201619011124027899693E8M2S3WOCKT9G6KHE11', 
                         '201619011124027899693E8M2S3WOCKT9G6KHE12' )
```

which runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE identifier NOT IN({0})", notIn), _connector.getMsConnection());
```

This way the value of notIn will be concat to your string query.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what the other answers say, concatenating the string to build the SQL is a bad idea, *especially* since the input values are strings. You open yourself up to SQL injection attacks.

You should be generating multiple parameters for each item in your list.

For example, if you have the input input:

```
var notIn = new[] { "A1", "B2", "C3" }
```

You'd want something like

```
for(var i = 0; i < notIn.Length; i++)
    command.AddParamWithValue("p"+i, notIn);
```

And then you can build the SQL with concatenation (note that we are not concatenating an *input* here)

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE identifier NOT IN(" + string.Join(",", notIn.Select(i,v) => { "@p" + i; }) + ")";
```

Which then would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE identifier NOT IN (@p0,@p1,@p2)
```

Alternatively, you could dump the values into a temporary table and do a join.

Note that the above is pseudocode, and may not compile *verbatim*, but should give you the right idea about how to procede.

Answer (score -1):

It's because, you passed the @notIn as a whole string, which means, the SQL server see it as:

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE identifier NOT IN('''201619011124027899693E8M2S3WOCKT9G6KHE11'',''201619011124027899693E8M2S3WOCKT9G6KHE12''')
```

So you got empty result

Try changing the "not in" to where clause and generate the where with C#:

```
string selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE";
selectStatement += " identifier != '201619011124027899693E8M2S3WOCKT9G6KHE11' and identifier != '201619011124027899693E8M2S3WOCKT9G6KHE12'";
```

Or if you really want to use parameterized SQL, try doing it in stored procedure instead.

Comment: Downvotes are OK, but please explain the reason for it.